# Newbie Django Question : Can't find data I thought I preset in a Form

Tags: django

I'm still getting to grips with Django and, in particular, Forms.

I created MyForm which subclasses forms.Form in which I define a field like this :

owner = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

When I create a new, blank instance of the Form I want to prefill this with the creator's profile, which I'm doing like this :

form = MyForm( {'owner' : request.user.get_profile()} )

Which I imagine sets the owner field of the form to the request.user's id. (The *type* of the corresponding "owner" field in the models.Model class is ForeignKey of Profile.)

Before rendering the form, I need to check one piece of information about the owner. So I try to access form.owner, but there seems to be no "owner" attribute of the form object. I also tried form.instance.owner, but similarly, no luck.

What am I doing wrong? What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this value via the form's data dictionary:

form.data.get('owner')

Comment: No prob. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Initial data in a form should be passed in with the [`initial` kwarg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values).

Once you've turned the form into a bound form (usually by passing `request.POST` in as the first argument to instantiate the form, the place you are currently incorrectly providing the initial dictionary), and performed validation with `form.is_valid()`, the data the user submitted will be in `form.cleaned_data`, a dictionary.  If they changed the initial value, their changed value will be in that dictionary.  If not, your initial value will be.

If you don't want to let the user modify the value, then don't have it be a field, instead pass it in as a `kwarg`, and store it as an instance attribute in `form.__init__()`:

```
class MyForm(Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, profile, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.profile = profile


...

form = MyForm(
    request.POST if request.POST else None,
    profile=request.user.get_profile(),
)

if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
    do_stuff_with(form.profile)
```

Also as with most things, this all gets easier if you drink the Django kool-aid and use generic views.

```
class MyView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        return {
            **super().get_form_kwargs(),
            "profile": self.request.user.get_profile()
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        do_stuff_with(form.profile)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Or for the `initial` case whereby you want it to be editable:

```
class MyView(FormView):
    form_class = MyForm
    ...

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
            **super().get_initial(),
            "profile": self.request.user.get_profile()
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        do_stuff_with(form.cleaned_data.get("profile"))

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

If `MyForm` happens to be a form about one single instance of a specific model then this gets even easier with `UpdateView` instead of `FormView`.  The more you buy into the way Django wants to do things, the less you have to work.